# How to speed up random writes in OpenCL kernel

Tags: memory, opencl

I have this OpenCL kernel for calculating the Buddhabrot-Set:

```
// ... initializing things
while (true)
    {
        Z2 = Z * Z;
        Z = (float2)(Z2.x - Z2.y + Point.x, 2 * Z.x * Z.y + Point.y);

        X = ((Z.x - MinView.x) * iScale.x);
        Y = ((Z.y - MinView.y) * iScale.y);

        if (X >= 0 && X < Res.x && Y >= 0 && Y < Res.y)
        {
            Result[Offset + Y * Res.x + X]++; // <--- Commenting out this line gives a 10x-speedup
            count++;
        }

        if (dot(Z, Z) > 4)
        {
            PointsOutPos = atomic_add(&atomicCounter[2], 1);
            if (PointsOutPos >= PointsOutSize)
                return;
            Point = convert_float2(PointsOut[PointsOutPos]); // Load next point to minimize thread divergence
            Z = 0;
            i = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Commenting out the line `Result[Offset + Y * Res.x + X]++` gives about a 10fold speedup (and of course no result). So the random writes seem to be a huge bottleneck. Not only will this writes be on random places in the output array but also they occur at different times/iterations (although in most iterations).

Does anybody have an idea how to speed this up? Using a local array as a buffer would not work because it would not change the writes - just the time they are done (and if done all at once would probably saturate the memory bandwidth). Or is my thinking wrong and other threads could calculate while memory is written?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do writes in atomic way. ++ will not work when multiple threads write to same result element which is race condition. This can change the performance but ofcourse it wont be anywhere near pure computation loop's performance. Writing to non-contiguous memory address will be inefficient.

To write contiguous chunks, you have to convert the pattern from scatter to gather. If buddhabrotset is not convertible to gather, then it will be slow just as any other implementation of buddhabrotset.

If atomic write is not fast, then try this:

- Write indices of to-be-written result elements from each thread into an array. But make the writes in strided pattern to increase chances of efficient memory write.
- serially parse it from cpu with "binning" algorithm like this:

  idx = index[i];
  result[idx]++;

This part will be fast. If index array is 8GB long then the cpu accessing it will take only few seconds.

---

Another approach can be having multiple output images, 1 per block of threads, to decrease maximum collisions per pixel to 256-ish value rather than millions. Then blend all output images into result.

If block size is 256 threads, then the sub-image can be made of unsigned char elements.

Maybe this helps gpu's atomic-function accelerator logic to decrease the scope of collision checking from global to local.

Comment: Shouldn't using atomic operations slow down the writes further? I didn't use atomic_add here because the Buddhabrot-set is statistical anyway. Race conditions should happen rarely and if they do, this would not ruin the result. An index array sounds interesting, I will give it a try and report back.

Comment: If race condition happens really rarely, then every pixel's thread writes only to 1 pixel on average? Then you should do "gather" approach instead of "scatter". But if they do a lot of writes to same pixels just not at the same time, then its still race condition because gpu blocks are cached / relaxed and not synchronized.

Comment: I tried the approach with an index array and it indeed speeds up the kernel a bit, but not by much. Race conditions should happen rarely, but every thread still might write to 1000s of pixels on average. Just from a correctness point of view atomic operations should not be necessary. Lots of writes to the same pixel but not at the same time will happen. Could you elaborate on "gpu blocks are cached / relaxed and not synchronized" and why that means race conditions?

Comment: I mean, unless programmer uses a sync insteuction in kernel, data stays cached until kernel ends. Some amd gpus (or drivers) even had cached data within same thread. Ofcourse iit was a bug but mostly gpus do not trade performance for coherence. Relaxed memory model is preferred in there.

Comment: But that would still only mean, the result would be more or less off, would it? The image my kernel creates looks perfectly fine, so race conditions should not be an issue (as I would expect in this case). So your "gather" approach would probably be the (only?) way to go? But as mentioned there is only a small speedup. A local buffer probably wouldn't do much either, because it would only delay writes a bit? Unless I could do some sorting/gathering so writes to global memory are coherent...

Comment: If it's not a scientific app, just do whatever is faster, until somebody complains. Every bug is a feature until proven otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a tile based approach to minimize global memory writes by using local memory as a buffer:

```
__kernel void buddhabrot(__global float2* PointsOut, __global int* Result, __global int* atomicCounter, 
                         int PointsOutSize, float2 MinView, float2 MaxView, int2 Res) {
    int id = get_global_id(0);
    if (id >= PointsOutSize) return;

    float2 Point = PointsOut[id];
    float2 Z = (0, 0);
    int2 iScale = (Res.x / (MaxView.x - MinView.x), Res.y / (MaxView.y - MinView.y));
    
    __local int localBuffer[LOCAL_SIZE]; // Define as per your tile size
    for (int i = 0; i < LOCAL_SIZE; i++) localBuffer[i] = 0;
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ITERATIONS; i++) {
        float2 Z2 = Z * Z;
        Z = (float2)(Z2.x - Z2.y + Point.x, 2 * Z.x * Z.y + Point.y);
        int2 pos = (int2)((Z.x - MinView.x) * iScale.x, (Z.y - MinView.y) * iScale.y);

        if (all(pos >= 0) && all(pos < Res)) {
            int localIdx = (pos.y % TILE_SIZE) * TILE_SIZE + (pos.x % TILE_SIZE);
            atomic_add(&localBuffer[localIdx], 1);
        }

        if (dot(Z, Z) > 4) break;
    }

    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    // Write back to global memory
    for (int i = 0; i < LOCAL_SIZE; i++) {
        if (localBuffer[i] > 0) {
            int globalIdx = calculateGlobalIndex(i, ...); // Implement this
            atomic_add(&Result[globalIdx], localBuffer[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But won't that just delay the writes until the thread has done its iterations and not change anything to the writes themselves? The kernel will have to do the exact same number of writes anyway except when some '++' could be combined to one '+=n', which is very unlikely...